# Scala Array Slicing with Tuple

Tags: arrays, scala, tuples

I try to slice an 1D `Array[Double]` using the `slice` method. I've written a method which returns the start and end index as a tuple `(Int,Int)`.

```
  def getSliceRange(): (Int,Int) = {
    val start =   ...
    val end =  ...
    return (start,end)
  }
```

How can I use the return value of `getSliceRange` directly?

I tried:

```
myArray.slice.tupled(getSliceRange())
```

But this gives my a compile-Error:

```
Error:(162, 13) missing arguments for method slice in trait IndexedSeqOptimized;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
  myArray.slice.tupled(getSliceRange())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the implicit conversion from `Array` to [`ArrayOps`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps) (which gets `slice` from `GenTraversableLike`).

```
val doubleArray = Array(1d, 2, 3, 4)

(doubleArray.slice(_, _)).tupled

Function.tupled[Int, Int, Array[Double]](doubleArray.slice)

(doubleArray.slice: (Int, Int) => Array[Double]).tupled
```

Comment: in short: `(myArray.slice(_, _)).tupled(getSliceRange())` does the trick.

Comment: Can you explain what `(doubleArray.slice(_, _)).tupled` means?

Comment: `doubleArray.slice(_, _)` is the same as `(a, b) => doubleArray.slice(a, b)`, we need the parentheses because we want to call `tupled` on the function and not on the result of `slice` .

Answer (score 1):

Two options here, the first one is to call your function twice:

```
myArray.slice(getSliceRange()._1, getSliceRange()._2)
```

or to save your `Tuple` beforehand:

```
val myTuple: (Int, Int) = getSliceRange()
myArray.slice(myTuple._1, myTuple._2)
```

Edit: I leave this here just in case but *Peter Neyens* posted the expected answer.